# Mantener sesión activa en Angular js (ionic framework)

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Estoy realizando un APP la cual tiene una pantalla de logeo (eso ya he realizado). Ahora lo que deseo hacer es mantener la sesión activa porque cuando minimizo la app o la cierro y al abrirla siempre me regresa a la PANTALLA DE LOGIN.

Lo que yo he estado realizando es utilizar una base de datos SQLITE (aunque se que no es recomendable utilizar pero no se que otra forma hacer) que guarda el estado de la sesión. si es igual a SESION_ACTIVA se muestra otra pantalla pero si no me muestra la de login.

Este es mi código:

APP.js

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite,$state) {//paso 2 agrego cordovaSqlite
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
      db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: 'tuto.db' });//paso 3 creo  la BD
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tutoria (id integer primary key, estado text)");
      //creo la tabla personas


      var query = "SELECT estado FROM tutoria";
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query).then(function(result) {
        for ( j=0; j < result.rows.length; j++) { 
          if(result.rows.item(j).estado=="Sesion_Activa"){
            $state.go('tabsEst.perfilEstudiante'); 
          }                         
        }
      });
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

  });
})
```

Y este es mi controller:

```
ServUsuario.servicioUs($scope.data.username,$scope.data.password).success(function(data){
      $scope.datos=data.token; //ingreso al token del json
      if($scope.datos=='true' && $scope.rol=='docente') {//si el token es true ingresa si no popUp de error
        $rootScope.cedula=data.persona.identificacion;
        $rootScope.pNombre=data.persona.primerNombre;
        $rootScope.NombreDoc=$rootScope.pNombre.substring(0, 1);//variable para mostrar en perfil de docente
        $rootScope.sNombre=data.persona.segundoNombre;
        $rootScope.pApellido=data.persona.primerApellido;
        $rootScope.sApellido=data.persona.segundoApellido;
        //PASO 4 SQLITE BASE DE DATOS
        var query = "INSERT INTO tutoria (estado) VALUES (?)";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query,["Sesion_Activa"]).then(function(result) {
          //alert("ID -> " + result.insertId);
        }, function(error) {
          //alert('error jj');
        });
        //FIN PASO 4 SQLITE BASE DE DATOS  
        $state.go('tabs.perfilDocente');
      } 
      else {
        if($scope.datos=='true' && $scope.rol=='estudiante') {//si el token es true ingresa si no popUp de error
          $rootScope.cedula=data.persona.identificacion;//las variables con rootscope tb pueden ser llamadas con scope.cedula x ej.
          $rootScope.pNombre=data.persona.primerNombre;
          $rootScope.NombreEst=$rootScope.pNombre.substring(0, 1);//variable para mostrar en perfil de estudiante
          $rootScope.sNombre=data.persona.segundoNombre;
          $rootScope.pApellido=data.persona.primerApellido;
          $rootScope.sApellido=data.persona.segundoApellido; 
          //PASO 4 SQLITE BASE DE DATOS
          var query = "INSERT INTO tutoria (estado) VALUES (?)";
          $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query,["Sesion_Activa"]).then(function(result) {
            //alert("ID -> " + result.insertId);
          }, function(error) {
            //alert('error jj');
          });
          //FIN PASO 4 SQLITE BASE DE DATOS 
          $state.go('tabsEst.perfilEstudiante');
        }else{
          var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Usuario o password incorrectos',
            template: 'Por favor intenta de nuevo!'
          });
        }        
      }
    })
    .error(function(data){
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Error en la comunicación con el servidor'
      });
    })
```

Lo que he venido realizando al parecer si funciona pero cuando consulto a la base de datos el valor de la sesión, si es correcta me muestra primero la de login pero pasa un segundo y se muestra `$state.go('tabsEst.perfilEstudiante');` que para mí sería correcto.

¿Quisiera saber si me pueden guiar o ayudar con esto de mantener sesiones activas en una aplicación, o si me pueden guiar en lo que actualmente estoy realizando?

Answer (score 3):

Usar un SQL no es mala idea en si misma, pues te da sus garantías. Pero creo que es la razón de por que sigues viendo la pantalla de login "por un segundo".

Apache Cordova, tiene un par de [eventos](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/cordova/events/events.html#Events) que vale la pena tener en cuenta, son "pause" y "resume", ambos sirven para detectar cuando la aplicación pasa a segundo plano y cuando pasa a primer plano, respectivamente.

En Ionic Framework, puedes configurar estos eventos por medio de  [$ionicPlatform.on(..)](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/#on).

Por otro lado en lugar de grabar en un SQL, te conviene utilizar [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) por velocidad y simpleza.

Finalmente para simplificar el código, en tu controller cuando rellenas la informacion del usuario, en lugar de agregar todos los datos al `$rootScope` directamente, hazlo utilizando un objeto intermedo.

```
$rootScope.cedula=data.persona.identificacion;
$rootScope.pNombre=data.persona.primerNombre;
$rootScope.NombreDoc=$rootScope.pNombre.substring(0, 1);
// etc..
```

Cámbialo por algo así:

```
var usuario = {};
usuario.cedula = data.persona.identificacion;
usuario.pNombre = data.persona.primerNombre;
// etc.. y luego
$rootScope.usuario = usuario;
```

### Todo Junto

Finalmente y asumiendo que hiciste el cambio sugerido en el controller:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    $ionicPlatform.on('pause', function() {
      localStorage.setItem('usuario', JSON.stringify($rootScope.usuario || {}));

      // opcionalmente puedes guardar la pagina donde se encuentra el usuario
      localStorage.setItem('hash', document.location.hash);
    });

    $ionicPlatform.on('resume', function() {
       var usuario = localStorage.getItem('usuario');
       $rootScope.usuario = JSON.parse(usuario);

       // restauras el estado cuando fue cerrada la app.
       document.location.hash = localStorage.getItem('hash');
    });   

  });

});
```

Luego, cuando se vuelve a abrir la aplicación, no necesitas volver a consultar el SQLite pues quedara restaurado el valor de `$rootScope.usuario`. Ten en cuenta que si tienes un botón de "Logout", tendrias que eliminar el usuario del local Storge.

```
localStorage.removeItem('usuario');
localStorage.removeItem('hash');
```

Comment: Antes de todo te agradezco por tomarte tu tiempo...tengo una pregunta
en mi controller debo agregar el valor hash o solo hago como tu me has puesto saludos..